# How to represent distinct query of mongo db in java language

Tags: java, mongodb

The Mongodb query:`db.inventory.distinct( "item.sku", { dept: "A" } )`

How can I write a equivalent code to the above query in java?

Comment: You may want to look at Java MongoDB Driver [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/).

Comment: Hi I done with connecting to mongo db in java..

Comment: Document d=new Document()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `item.sku` is of a String Type, you can fire your distinct query like this:

```
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
filter.put( "dept", "A" );

MongoCursor<String> c = db.getCollection("inventory").distinct("item.sku", filter, String.class).iterator();
```

Hope this helps.